# ErrorDocument redirection from any directory to a file with relative links - most compact way

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I have a php file that works like a custom message displayer. I pass some variables with GET and it displays a message based on that. It also works as a 404 error page. The problem is; it has **relative** references, which are highly desirable because of portability, but they don't seem to work, after my `ErrorDocument` redirection to that file.

file's location: `/a/b/c/custom_message_displayer.php`

When `httpd.conf` is set to:

`ErrorDocument 404 /a/b/c/custom_message_displayer.php?e=404`

and the error comes from a subdirectory eg. `/a/blah`, the **active** directory is in this case `/a/`, not the `/a/b/c/` to where `ErrorDocument` is redirecting, and that results in mislinking in the file (relative css, js, include() paths).

I made a workaround that uses an additional file. But i'm concerned about this, and wonder if there's some more simple way of doing this. Perhaps an `httpd.config`-based redirection that also changes the active directory?

The workaround:

`ErrorDocument 404 /additional_file.php` → this file redirects using:
`header('Location: /a/b/c/custom_message_displayer.php')` also preserving/forwarding the GET query.

The file then gets executed in it's directory, and all relative links work.

Is there a simplier way of doing the above? Thanks for any bit of advice.

Comment: Relative URLs are expanded by the browser, not the server. The browser doesn't know the location of the script, it just knows the URL it used to get it.

Comment: So, one has to force redirect on the user's browser to that directory. I wondered if this could be done with `RewriteEngine` triggered by `ErrorDocument`.